# swift function to iterate possibly reversed array

Tags: swift

I'd like to create a function that will iterate over an array (or collection or sequence). Then I will call that function with an array, and the reversed version of the array (but efficiently: without creating a new array to hold the reverse).

If I do this:

```
func doIteration(points: [CGPoint]) {
  for p in points {
     doSomethingWithPoint(p)
  }
  // I also need random access to points
  doSomethingElseWithPoint(points[points.count-2]) // ignore obvious index error
}
```

And if I have this:

```
let points : [CGPoint] = whatever
```

I can do this just fine:

```
doIteration(points)
```

But then if I do this:

```
doIteration(points.reverse())
```

I get 'Cannot convert value of type 'ReverseRandomAccessCollection<[CGPoint]> to expected argument type [_]'

Now, I DON'T want to do this:

```
let reversedPoints : [CGPoint] = points.reverse()
doIteration(reversedPoints)
```

even though it will work, because that will (correct me if I'm wrong) create a new array, initializing it from the ReverseRandomAccessCollection returned by reverse().

So I guess I'd like to write my doIteration function to take some sort of sequence type, so I can pass in the result of reverse() directly, but ReverseRandomAccessCollection doesn't conform to anything at all. I think I'm missing something - what's the accepted pattern here?

Comment: `doIteration(points.reverse())` *does* compile. What you probably meant is `let rev  = points.reverse() ; doIteration(rev)` which causes the error message that you described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your parameter's type to a generic, you should get the functionality you need:

```
func doIteration
  <C: CollectionType where C.Index: RandomAccessIndexType,  C.Generator.Element == CGPoint>
  (points: C) {
  for p in points {
    doSomethingWithPoint(p)
  }
  doSomethingElseWithPoint(points[points.endIndex - 2])
}
```

More importantly, this *won't* cause a copy of the array to be made. If you look at the type generated by the `reverse()` method:

```
let points: [CGPoint] = []

let reversed = points.reverse() // ReverseRandomAccessCollection<Array<__C.CGPoint>>

doIteration(reversed)
```

You'll see that it just creates a struct that references the original array, in reverse. (although it does have value-type semantics) And the original function can accept this new collection, because of the correct generic constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
let reversedPoints : [CGPoint] = points.reverse()
doIteration(reversedPoints)
```

or this

```
doIteration(points.reverse() as [CGPoint])
```

but I don't think there is any real difference by the point of view of a the footprint.

### Scenario 1

```
let reversedPoints : [CGPoint] = points.reverse()
doIteration(reversedPoints)
```

Infact in this case a new Array containing **references** to the `CGPoint(s)` present in the original array is created. This thanks to the **Copy-on-write** mechanism that Swift used to manage structures.

So the memory allocated is the following:

> points.count * sizeOf(pointer)

### Scenario 2

On the other hand you can write something like this

```
doIteration(points.reverse() as [CGPoint])
```

But are you really saving memory? Let's see.
A temporary variable is created, that variable is available **inside** the scope of the function `doIteration` and requires exactly a pointer for each element contained in `points` so again we have:

> points.count * sizeOf(pointer)

So I think you can safely choose one of the 2 solutions.

### Considerations

We should remember that Swift manages structures in a very smart way.

When I write

```
var word = "Hello"
var anotherWord = word
```

On the first line Swift create a Struct and fill it with the value "Hello".
On the second line Swift detect that there is no real reason to create a copy of the original String so writes inside the `anotherWord` a reference to the original value.

Only when `word` or `anotherWord` is modified Swift really create a copy of the original value.